coding a chrome extension , why after create a vue instance, div app disappear
my extension code is like this:
popup.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shit2excel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="static/js/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/axios.min.js"></script>
   
    <style>
        body {
            width: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <h1 class="my-4">Item Info Export</h1>
        <h1>hello world</h1>
        <button @click="exportItemInfo" class="btn btn-primary">Export</button>
    </div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

popup.js 
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        productInfo: [
            { name: 'item_1', price: 100, quantity: 10 },
            { name: 'item_2', price: 200, quantity: 5 },
            { name: 'item_3', price: 150, quantity: 8 },
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        exportItemInfo() {
            const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.productInfo);
            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'item_info.xlsx');
        }
    }
});

load the extension in chrome ,  and the popup page is blank, the div app disappear , not any error in console .
vue is version 2.7.16
the all code is in  https://github.com/digjack/shit2excel

You might not need to import axios nowadays + use Vue3. The rest I'm not sure fully. Check if you can see some basic HTML first I'd say. Or give a try to this starter to maybe get some inspiration as of how to build something modern that still follows the Manifest v3. https://github.com/antfu-collective/vitesse-webext

Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

yet, I known the separate console window, and the blank is the popup up page console window result.
